# How to Show Specific product on cms page in magento.?

Tags: magento

> I want to display some specific products on cms page in magento. I
>   searched alot but find nothing. Any Help .?

Comment: You should read the tour and check how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a new category and put your products inside, set it so it doesn't appear on the navigation- so you get a hidden category.

Then on your CMS page add a block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="ENTER_YOUR_CAT_ID" product_count="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

also if you have predefined columns you can use 'column_count' variable:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="COLUMN_COUNT_NO" category_id="ENTER_YOUR_CAT_ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```